# What makes a hero?

Tags: java, gui, javafx

This is a simple program meant to show how dynamic JavaFX is. It moves one list item to another and back without having to update the screen directly, thanks to the Observable Collection classes. It also exemplifies how links would work.

In the same vein as [Hello parallel world](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93057/hello-parallel-world), I practiced and illustrated some ideas with the intention of teaching a friend later on. I'm curious about what could be improved, and if anything is done poorly or inefficiently.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Heroes extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints(150, 150, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        column1.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        ColumnConstraints column2 = new ColumnConstraints(60);

        ColumnConstraints column3 = new ColumnConstraints(150, 150, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        column3.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
        gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        gridpane.setHgap(10);
        gridpane.setVgap(10);
        gridpane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(column1, column2, column3);

        Label candidatesLabel = new Label("Candidates");
        GridPane.setHalignment(candidatesLabel, HPos.CENTER);
        gridpane.add(candidatesLabel, 0, 0);

        Label heroesLabel = new Label("Heroes");
        GridPane.setHalignment(heroesLabel, HPos.CENTER);
        gridpane.add(heroesLabel, 2, 0);

        final ObservableList<String> candidates = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Wonder Woman",
            "Batman",
            "Superman",
            "Daenerys");
        final ListView<String> candidatesListView = new ListView<>(candidates);
        gridpane.add(candidatesListView, 0, 1);

        final ObservableList<String> heroes = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Code Reviewers");
        final ListView<String> heroListView = new ListView<>(heroes);
        gridpane.add(heroListView, 2, 1);

        Button sendRight = new Button(" > ");
        sendRight.setOnAction( e -> {
            String potential = candidatesListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (potential != null) {
                candidates.remove(potential);
                heroes.add(potential);
            }
        });

        Button sendLeft = new Button(" < ");
        sendLeft.setOnAction(e -> {
            String notHero = heroListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (notHero != null) {
                heroListView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                heroes.remove(notHero);
                candidates.add(notHero);
            }
        });

        Button qualify = new Button(" qualify ");
        qualify.setOnAction(e -> viewQualification(heroListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()));

        VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
        vbox.setPrefWidth(65);
        setSameWidth(vbox, sendRight, sendLeft, qualify);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(sendRight, sendLeft, qualify);
        gridpane.add(vbox, 1, 1);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(gridpane);
        GridPane.setVgrow(root, Priority.ALWAYS);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 250));
        stage.setTitle("What makes a hero?");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void viewQualification(String target) {
        try {
            switch(target) {
                case "Wonder Woman":
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(
                        new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=327&v=fOWLqnjFN64?t=12s"));
                break;
                case "Batman":
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(
                        new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpu6yPAFHrs?t=12s"));
                break;
                case "Superman":
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(
                        new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYSxN4ezhO4?t=12s"));
                break;
                case "Daenerys":
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(
                        new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4PPWYCqPKo?t=15s"));
                break;
                case "Code Reviewers":
                    showMessage(" Yes, fellow CRer, you are my hero.  ;) ");
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setSameWidth(VBox vbox, Button... buttons) {
        for (Button button : buttons) {
            button.setMinWidth(vbox.getPrefWidth());
        }
    }

    public static void showMessage(String message) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Label label = new Label(message);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(label));
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 male and 2 female superheros... Very politically correct ;-)

I suggest to try to avoid repeated code as much as possible.
For example,
`Desktop.getDesktop().browse(...)` is used in most of the `case` statements,
only the URL parameter is different.
I would refactor this in a way that the `case` statements set a URL variable,
so that you can write the `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(...)` call one time,
after the `switch`.

Of course, this won't apply to Code Reviewers.
In that case, `return` from the switch,
instead of setting a URL.

Another kind of duplication in your code is that of the names of superheros:
they appear first when you add them to the `candidates` list,
and then again in the `case` statements.
As such, it seems it would be better to use a `Map<String, String>` (or `Map<String, URI>`,
and do without the `switch`.

Answer (score 6):

Having links to YouTube videos hard-coded in your application is not ideal. The linked videos could be removed, inaccessible in certain locations along with many more reasons that make this ill-advised.

```
 new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=327&v=fOWLqnjFN64?t=12s")
```

You could extract the links into a properties file and read it at the start of the application. This way you don't have to open the code of your application to update the links.

---

As always this is not really helpful :

```
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Printing the stack trace most of the time won't do any good. Since it's a simple application, I do not have a recommendation. Just pointing out that this achieves nothing, at this point you may as well remove the print and just include a comment like `//Suppressing exception`